# return type of a react component typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following component:

```
const MyComponent: React.FC = function(){
  return "hello world"
}
```

It's correct, and it's not false, however, typescript is complaining that this is not correct because the return type is a string, it thinks that it should be a JSX element.

Then what is the correct type to use here?

I want to simply define a component, so it will still understand the types of the parameters, so the *props* and the *ref*,

so it's still a component,

I don't want to write

`: string` as the return type simply because it's not totally correct, it's not a normal function it's a component.

But I think that the implementation of the `FC` type is either wrong or that I should use another type.

Which type defines a component?

Comment: You should wrap your string in a fragment, so it matches the expected return type of JSX.Element: https://tsplay.dev/wXvROm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it is discouraged to use `React.FunctionComponent` or it's shorthand `React.FC`. I have found that it ends up causing friction and churn for very little gain. You can read more about it [here](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/function_components), but here's the lowdown:

Pros of using `React.FC`:

- more explicit
- it provides typechecking and autocomplete for static properties like displayName, propTypes, and defaultProps.
- (pre v18) automatically includes `children` in the props... which is not always desirable

Cons of using `React.FC`:

- extremely verbose, hard to read, "gets in your way" when you just want to make a component
- (pre v18) automatically includes `children` in the props, which is not always desirable

I stopped using it a couple years ago when they initially discouraged it, and I couldn't be happier. You literally just write functions as you normally would and TS will infer the return type. I generally define my props separately like this:

```
type MyComponentProps =  {...};

const MyComponent = ({ ... }: MyComponentProps) => {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I think this would answer the question if it provided an alternative, not just saying "don't use React.FC" (but I totally agree).

Comment: The alternative is literally nothing. Typescript will infer everything. Just write functions. I'll update the answer to include this.

Comment: Right, sooooo include it in the answer :)

Comment: "Don't use a return type" is a non-answer to a question asking for a return type. Can you update the answer to suggest a correct return type?

Comment: Sometimes the people asking the question don't know what the recommended way of doing something is. If you want to help someone make their life more difficult, be my guest. As someone who has been writing react code since react v14, I would highly highly discourage anybody from using the explicit return type. Look at how much time the OP has lost already... for nothing... literally no gain will come of this. And hopefully someone else in the future will find my answer and save themselves the unnecessary headache.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75861152/return-type-of-a-react-component-typescript#comment133811499_75861219) @RyanWheale Explicit return types as valuable as all other types. Just as type annotations in other positions help prevent mistakes at those sites, return types help prevent unexpected/incorrect return values.

Comment: TS will bark at you if you try to use the component and the return type is invalid, which is definitely "good enough" when the tradeoff is unnecessary verbosity, loss of developer time, code readability and maintainability, et al. Again, I'm not the one who discourages it... take it up with the maintainers of the react types and create-react-app. They are the ones to talk to.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `React.ReactNode`:

```
type Props = {
    // ...
}

function MyComponent(props: Props): React.ReactNode {
    return 'Hello world!'
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCmATzCTgAUcwBnOAXjgG8K4+4A9ALgA6MRQC+FCkgAekWHEwBXAHYZgEVXACy1AMK5IqpKpgAKMMxYAuRtYCUd5OhgiXGAHIQAJvR7k-HBEMMpQ2vgAEkgANjEQcADu0DE+AIRk5BJAA

Comment: This is a great answer to the question, but can you justify your opinion ("_I would use..._") — e.g. by citing external (perhaps first-party) information?

Comment: No, I can't actually, which is why I want to keep the "personal opinion" disclaimer here.